# How to use Node jQuery in Javascript to access JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Node jQuery to try and get some JSON data from the Twitch API. I currently have the code

```
require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    var $ = require("jquery") (window);
});
```

at the top of my `app.js` (as said at https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery), and my code to access the data is:

```
if (message === "!followers") {
    $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/lirik?client_id=XXX", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

using TMI.js. However when I start my bot I get the error `"TypeError: require(...).jsdom(...).createWindow is not a function"`, see full error: https://gyazo.com/44a48caaee0b8e2b547ecd7746972f66

Comment: Why on earth are you using jQuery to fetch data from a server? There are many, many better options. I'd suggest [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) to start with.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't know node fetch